# use auxiliary input with keras in middle of network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following models, one is used for calculating trajectories, the other for judging them. The scoring model has all layers, the targeting one only the first half. Both need the targeting parameters to calculate a trajectory and then scoring it respectively. In order for the scoring model to have access to the targeting data, it needs it as an auxiliary input (since the targeting output only has 2 values). I tried achieving this using a concatenate layer, but it gives me an error:

```
# targeting_model
inp=layers.Input(4)

tdense1=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inp)
tdense2=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(tdense1)
tdense3=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(tdense2)

tout=layers.Dense(2, activation='linear')(tdense3)

# scoring_model
auxinp=layers.Input(4)

sinp=layers.Concatenate()([tout,auxinp])
sdense1=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(sinp)
sdense2=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(sdense1)
sout=layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(sdense2)






targeting_model =  tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=tout, name="targeting_model")
print(targeting_model.summary())
scoring_model =  tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=sout, name="scoring_model")
```

Here's the error:

```
ValueError`: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") at layer "concatenate". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['dense', 'dense_1', 'dense_2', 'dense_3']`
```

but the tout layer is fully connected and the auxinput layer is just an input layer. So why is it saying the graph is disconnected?

EDIT: Figured it out. Needed to add auxinp to inputs in Model()

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add auxinp to model inputs

```
# targeting_model
inp=layers.Input(4)

tdense1=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inp)
tdense2=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(tdense1)
tdense3=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(tdense2)

tout=layers.Dense(2, activation='linear')(tdense3)

# scoring_model
auxinp=layers.Input(4)

sinp=layers.Concatenate()([tout,auxinp])
sdense1=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(sinp)
sdense2=layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(sdense1)
sout=layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(sdense2)






targeting_model =  tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=tout, name="targeting_model")
print(targeting_model.summary())
scoring_model =  tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp,auxinp], outputs=sout, name="scoring_model")
```